# My computer screen expanded and rotated

Tags: windows-10

My computer screen became expanded and rotated. I think it's because my brother installed something. Its not a normal rotate, it expanded as well; I can't see half of the screen as it's rotated 90 degrees.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since other people can't see your screen, it can be hard to understand exactly what's going on.  It would be helpful if you could snap a picture of the screen and post a link here to where people can view it on a public sharing site, like imgur.com.  If one of the answers solves the problem, please click the checkmark next to it, which will let people know that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: I don't believe this is unclear. Yes, OP doesn't have the common words to describe their issue, but there is information enough to understand what is being said: After their brother used their computer, the screen images are rotated and the resolution has changed (or possibly scaling was activated), and they need assistance getting it back to normal.

Answer (score 5):

## Computer screen expanded

1. **Right click on the desktop and select Display settings.**

[image]

2. **Click on Advanced display settings**.
3. **Set the Resolution** to what ever you will like, (i.e 1600 x 900) or set as Recommended.
4. **Click Apply**.

## Computer screen rotated

1. **Right click on the desktop and select Display settings.**

[image]

2. **Choose a screen** to fix if you have multiple monitors attached. Skip this step if you have only one.
3. **Select Landscape** from the orientation menu.

[image]

4. **Click Apply** (or OK)

[image]

5. **Click Keep Changes** when prompted.

[image]

[Source](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/fix-sideways-screen-computer)

Answer (score 1):

Please verify for yourself, but I believe from my days at school, cmd (windows key) + shift + directional arrow, will rotate your screen to that direction. I hope this helps.

UPDATE
I think it may actually be Ctrl + Alt + Arrow key.
Thanks @PrashantKumar96

Comment: Don't know about `Win key + Shift + Arrow key` but `Ctrl + Alt + Arrow key`, a hotkey defined by Intel Graphics, perform the task of screen rotation too.

Comment: Maybe this is what I meant. Sorry such a long time ago! I think you may be right. I will edit